# Community modified records

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

Of late I am seeing many questions getting modified by commity user? Is this a system updating questions or one of our admins updating the older questions?

Why do I see 2015/2016 questions pop back into the top queue?

Anyone noticing similar behavior?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48578/what-can-cause-a-question-to-be-bumped

Comment: Mod actions are visible as such in edit logs, and always from our own username.

Comment: I saw atleast questions back from 2016 at a point where community was editing bringing them to the newest queue. Hence assumed mod edits possibly could be one reason